# can not disable a .btn-default when submitting a modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an asp.net vmc5 and i am using bootstrap 3.0 & jQuery 1.10.2, now i wrote the following script:

```
function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('.btn btn-default').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#progress').show();
        if ($(this).valid()) {

            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
```

and my modal popup that got submitted looks as follow:-

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" /> |  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<span id="progress" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
                <img src="~/img/ajax-loaders/ajax-loader-5.gif" alt="wait" />
                Wait..
            </span>
```

but now when i submit the form the progress image will be shown (as mentioned inside the script)  , but the submit button will not get disabled ? can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector is invalid try this:-

```
 $('.btn.btn-default').prop("disabled", "disabled");
```